# Is $\{0\}$ open in $\mathbb{Q}?$

Tags: real-analysis

Is $\{0\}$ an open subset in the metric space of $\mathbb{Q}?$

I am confused because I don't know how to determine whether a single point is open or closed.

Comment: Can you find an $r>0$ such that $\{x\in\mathbb Q\mid d(0,x)<r\}\subseteq\{0\}$?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Please use MathJax.

Comment: Which metric are you using?

Comment: Complement of {0} in Q. Open?

Comment: @PeterSzilas just because a subset of $\Bbb Q$ is closed, doesn't mean that it can't also be open.  This is particularly important to remember in $\Bbb Q$ under the absolute value metric, where sets such as $\{x  \in \Bbb Q:  x^2 < 2\}$ will be both closed and open.

Comment: Omnomnonom.Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you're referring to the usual metric on $\Bbb Q$, i.e. $d(x,y) = |x-y|$.

Recall the definition of an open set. A set $S \subset X$ is open (in a metric space $X$) if, for every $x \in S$, there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $y\in X$: $d(x,y) < \epsilon$ implies that $y \in S$.

With this, we see that $S = \{0\}$ fails to be an open subset of $X = \Bbb Q$.  In particular: whichever $\epsilon > 0$ you choose, I can find a value of $n$ so that $y = 1/n < \epsilon$, which means that $y \notin S$ but $d(0,y) = |0-1/n| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Omnomnomnom.Thanks again for your clarification.After struggling a bit : the set in.your comment is also closed in Q!!, I was a bit slow in understanding that we consider only rational !! accumulation points ( √2,-√2 are ruled out).

Comment: @PeterSzilas You're welcome.  Another point worth noting is that for an arbitrary metric space $X$, the subsets $X$ and $\emptyset$ are both closed and open (i.e. "clopen"). $X$ will have other clopen subsets whenever it fails to be connected.

Comment: Omnomnomnom.Thanks again for your kind clarifications, hope I do not fall into these kind of traps again:)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, what you have to do in this case is apply the definition of open subset: $A\in\mathbb{Q}$ is open if for every point $p\in A \ \exists r>0$ such that $B(p,r)\subset A.$

In the case of $A$, the only point $p$ is $p=0,$ so you have to check the property justifier that point. Unfortunately, for every $r>0$ we have that $\exists n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac1n<r.$ 
For this reason $\frac1n\in B(0,r)$ but $\frac1n\in \mathbb{Q}\setminus A$ because $\frac1n$ is not zero. So, we can conclude that for every $r>0,$ we have that $B(0,r)\not\subset A.$ Thus, $A$ is not open.